# ¿Cómo enlazo la main activity a otras activitys en android?

Tags: android, activity

Estoy haciendo una app sencilla, pero deseo abrir demás activitys desde la principal pero no lo he logrado, adjunto el código de las 2 clases de java la main y la que quiero enlazar, parece que falta algo en el *manifest.xml*. 
**main.java:**

```
package com.example.eduarceleita.asteroides;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**AcercaDe.java:**

```
package com.example.eduarceleita.asteroides;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class AcercaDe extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acercade);
    }
    public void lanzarAcercaDe(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AcercaDe.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

este es el codigo del manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AcercaDe"
              android:label="Acerca de..."
              android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"/>

</application>
```

este es el Main_activity:

```
   <Button
        android:text="Acerca de"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="lanzarAcercaDe"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
```

Comment: ¿Dentro de _Acerca de_ tienes la función para pasar a la misma actividad _Acerca de_? O ¿quieres que en el main te mande a _Acerca de_? Si es así la función _lanzarAcercaDe_ tienes que ponerla en la actividad _main_ y  llamarla dentro de `OnCreate`

Comment: si señor eso ya está hecho

Comment: Pues no lo veo, ya que la función no está dentro de `MainActivity`

Comment: claro que si, ya le adjunto el codigo del main activity
   <Button
        android:text="Acerca de"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="lanzarAcercaDe"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

Comment: @EduarCeleita Veo el código del botón que llama el método para el Intent y es correcto, me parece que tienes todo correcto, cual es el problema ahora, algún mensaje en el LogCat?

Comment: al momento de abrir el boton acerca de el cual me debe arrojara a otra activity se me cierra la app

Answer (score 3):

El método para realizar el Intent debe estar dentro de `MainActivity` para poder abrir `AcercaDe`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

      public void lanzarAcercaDe(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AcercaDe.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

El método se debe llamar desde un botón dentro del layout a traves de la propiedad  `android:onClick`, ejemplo:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    ..
    ..
    android:onClick="lanzarAcercaDe" />
```

---

Otra forma de realizarlo es llamando el método desde MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lanzarAcercaDe();
        }

          public void lanzarAcercaDe(){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AcercaDe.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
```

---

Asegura tener registradas tus Actividades como comenta cheko506 dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar esto al manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.example.eduarceleita.asteroides.AcercaDe"/>
```

Y por lo que veo debes poner ese intent dentro de la actividad de MainActivity y no dentro de AcerdaDe.

Comment: en que parte del main activity, es decir estoy leyendo a segunda edicion del gran libro de android y pues segun ese texto solo me falta adicionar el activity en el manifest.xml pero no se ha podido :(

Comment: agregalo dentro del tag de application

Comment: si señor, ya lo agregue